# c++ how to have a user input equation to be evaluated

Tags: c++, user-input

My program is meant to ask a user to input an equation. Then find the maximum over an interval given by the user. When I compile my program, the output I get is:

```
Please complete the equation to be evaluated f(x)= 
Please enter the first number of the interval to be checked: 
Please enter the last number of the interval to be checked: 
Please enter the desired initial step size: 
sh: PAUSE: command not found
```

with the last line repeating many times.
I think the problem here has something to do with having the user input the equation to be tested. However, I'm unsure of how to fix this.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, delta, fx, x, y;
    int max = 0;

    cout <<"Please complete the equation to be evaluated f(x)= " << endl;
    cin >> fx;
    cout <<"Please enter the first number of the interval to be checked: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please enter the last number of the interval to be checked: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Please enter the desired initial step size: " << endl;
    cin >> delta;

    for(x = a; x <= b; x = x+delta)                                
    {
        y = fx;     
        if (y > max)  
        { 
            max = y;  
            cout <<"The maximum over the interval from " << a <<"to " << b <<"is " << delta;
        }
        else
        {
            delta= delta/2;
        }
        if (delta <  pow( 10, -6))
        {
            system ("PAUSE");
        }
    }      

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the form of `fx`? Is it a number? Because that's what your code suggests, and - frankly - it has no sense.

Comment: fx is supposed to be the equation input by the user

Comment: Equation in what form? And why did you declare it as a number?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by the first question. And I wasn't sure what to declare it as.

Answer (score 2):

F(x) shouldn't be an integer variable, it should be a string variable. That way, the user can enter operators as characters instead of the compiler thinking they should be numbers. You would then have to process the string to determine the equation; this would require some thought, and possibly a more advanced data structure such as a binary tree.

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't use `system("pause");` in the if statement and you'll lose that error: 
**"sh: PAUSE: command not found"**. Place it right before the end of the main.

```
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: why not `system("pause")`?

Comment: sorry I just copied OP's original code. But its the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, the form of **f(x)** could be an issue with the above code.

Consider to redesign what to achieve for your program. One possibility is to narrow down the **f(x)** as polynomial function so that you can avoid parsing general algebraic equation, in this case you can ask: 
how many degree of the polynomial ? upon this, it is followed by input the coefficient value for each factor in the polynomial equation.

This way, you can still use integer (or *double* - better) in the program.

Comment: How would I have the program ask for the correct number of coefficients?

Comment: you can add extra step (input): e.g. cout << "how many coeffs?\n"; cin >> numcoeffs; for(int i = 0; i<numcoeffs; ++i) .. // iterate input for each coeffs here -- the f(x) could be fx = fx + a[i] * std::pow(x, i);